# How to Loop Function VBA Excell

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I want to apply this code to Cells (P2 to P300) but i don't know how to write it.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("P2")) Is Nothing Then
    Dim Fl2 As String
    Fl2 = Range("O2")
    Call Shell("explorer.exe /select," & Fl2, vbNormalFocus)
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("P3")) Is Nothing Then
    Dim Fl3 As String
    Fl3 = Range("O3")
    Call Shell("explorer.exe /select," & Fl3, vbNormalFocus)
    End If
```

How to get more easy way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cleaned up a bit using `Intersect` on the entire range and `Offset` to refer to the corresponding cell in column O.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("P2:P200")) Is Nothing Then
        Shell "explorer.exe /select," & Target.Offset(,-1).Value, vbNormalFocus
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The Insersect statement accepts multi-cell range

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("P2:P300")) Is Nothing Then
        Dim Fl As String
        Fl = Range("O" & Target.Row)
        Call Shell("explorer.exe /select," & Fl, vbNormalFocus)
    End If
End Sub
```